Chatgpt API keeps returning Error:404 Failed to get response from API
I am using ChatGPT's API for text classification task, which I upload a dataset and ask the ChatGPT to decide whether my text has something to do with real estate. My code is:
Basic Setup
import json
import requests
from os import getenv

# Load JSON data from file
with open('/policy_cleaned.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

# API settings
api_url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/completions"
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": f"Bearer sk-proj-...1u"
}


API Function
def classify_text(text):
    prompt = f"Classify the following text whether it is related to the Chinese real estate industry, and if it is specifically about Chinese real estate policy: {text}"
    payload = {
        "model": "gpt-4-turbo",  
        "prompt": prompt,
        "max_tokens": 64,
        "temperature": 0.1
    }
    response = requests.post(api_url, headers=headers, json=payload)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        result = response.json()
        return result
    else:
        return {"error": "Failed to get response from API", "status_code": response.status_code}


Run on my dataset and output response
results = []
for item in data:
    classification = classify_text(item['CleanedContent'])
    results.append({
        "PolicyID": item['PolicyID'],
        "Title": item['Title'],
        "Classification": classification
    })

with open('classified_data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    json.dump(results, file, ensure_ascii=False)

The program keeps returning in the returning JSON file:

{"error": "Failed to get response from API", "status_code": 404}.

I am a rookie using this, so I am desperate for any help!

It might help if you showed us the actual full api response (minus your API key of course), instead of deliberately hiding most of it.

The head of the responding json is like:
[{"PolicyID": 201200000026, "Title": "关于印发<中央补助城市棚户区改造专项资金管理办法>的通知", "Classification": {"error": "Failed to get response from API", "status_code": 404}}, {"PolicyID": 201200000010, "Title": "关于印发<中央补助廉租住房保障专项资金管理办法>的通知", "Classification": {"error": "Failed to get response from API", "status_code": 404}}, {"PolicyID": 201200000021, "Title": "上海市2012年共有产权保障房(经济适用住房)准入标准和供应标准", "Classification": {"error": "Failed to get response from API", "status_code": 404}}

Here's a modified version of your classify_text method that should work. The changes are based on the examples used in OpenAI's API Reference.
import json
import requests

def classify_text(text):
    system = "Classify the following text whether it is related to the Chinese real estate industry, and if it is specifically about Chinese real estate policy"
    payload = json.dumps({
        "model": "gpt-4-turbo",  
        "messages": [
            {"role": "system", "content": system},
            {"role": "user", "content": text}
        ],
        "max_tokens": 64,
        "temperature": 0.1
    })
    response = requests.post(api_url, headers=headers, data=payload)

    # Consider printing the response output to debug any issues
    print(response.json())
    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        result = response.json()
        return result
    else:
        return {"error": "Failed to get response from API", "status_code": response.status_code}



AH! It's my API key isssue, maybe I should figure out the billing issue first! Thanks!
